# state type infrence is any in main state file Context API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting state type as any in my main context api state file how to make ts know that the state type in useReducer is same as default state ?

```js
export const defaultState: StateInterface = {
  data : false,
}
export const globalContext = createContext(defaultState);

const GlobalProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(globalReducer, defaultState)
  }
```

Comment: `createContext` takes a type argument, you aren't passing in `StateInterface`

Comment: Should be `createContext<StateInterface>(defaultState)`

Comment: defaultState: StateInterface thus createContext infrence the state, still not working :(, the problem is with in the reducer for some reason....

Comment: @stop-error just setting the type of the `defaultState` variable is not enough to type your context. You have to use the type argument like Joel shows in his comment above.